# Can I add a KML file in GoogleMaps with a local path in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

Below is my JavaScript code.
Please localize my path thrown by my open `.kml` file in GoogleMaps:

```
function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 23.026261,  lng: 72.566872}
    });     

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
     url: 'http://exaple.com//aa.kml',
      map: map
    });
}
```

**My questions are:**
Can I add a local path in JavaScript?
Can I add a dynamic change to a `.kml` file in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Google processes KML layers on their servers and returns tile imagery for KML layers you provided. In order to process KML on server side they need upload your KML file to their server. That means you cannot use URL that is not accessible publicly from the web, so local path won't work.

Unfortunately, you cannot use local paths in KML layers.